# More about membership

Tags: discussion

In the [Does Graphic Design have a low voting problem?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361/does-graphic-design-have-a-low-voting-problem) the wording of "Intermediate Professional Designers" helped me realize this. Who are "Intermediate Professional Designers"?

Then I began researching StackExchange - Area51 to find where these intermediate users might be hiding.

- http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40151/typography
- http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/43017/adobe-creative-suite
- http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/43099/color-science
- http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42366/calligraphy
- http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/39226/digital-publications
- http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/17872/marketing
- http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40299/inkscape

Most of these should be completely closed in my opinion as being part of our Q&A already. Color-science should be split between us and Cogsci depending on the individual scope of the question. Marketing is more difficult but in my opinion questions like "Is a marketing degree crucial for a job in an ad agency?", "Is print advertising really dead?" and "When can I find (online) great photos for my marketing campaign?" Can go in ours. I know most of the designs that get submitted to me come from a marketing person because I work in budget advertising where companies can't afford a marketer and a graphic designer.

And the most telling of all:
https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6142/why-this-proposal-is-not-a-duplicate-of-the-graphic-design-proposal

Especially as we look to broaden our user base I think these are things we need to be looking into. Both to make sure that questions we can answer are redirected to us as the only one close to being a full site, and to make sure people know we exist rather than creating new proposals for every little thing.

Comment: Completely agree, these proposals could be merged and incorporated to GD. Very well spotted.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great find and really does address one of the areas of improvement that I see emerging as I talk to you all.

The usual course of action is to **post discussions in these overlapping proposals** explaining why they possibly overlap. Then **invite those users to the Graphic Design site** and let them know that we would love to see their questions here. It's possible that the people proposing these sites either don't know Graphic Design exists or aren't aware that their questions are actually on topic. Let them know that. This is also the way to expand the userbase here on Graphic Design.

The community team usually starts evaluating proposals once they reach 45%, so decisions about whether or not to close or merge proposals most likely won't be made before then.

Answer (score 1):

Posting as answer because it got too long. Unfortunately, half of these proposals have less than a dozen followers, some of whom might be the same ones across them. I think it would be definitely interesting to attract more typography people (where are they hiding?), and perhaps think about how parts of the marketing proposal could be introduced to give a larger scope. Inkscape and Gimp should also have a more active participation in GD, they would add terribly to the site (I was surprised there wasn't a proposal for open source graphic programs).